# Table Sorting not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have this code to try and sort the table by lowest price to highest price (the table is populated by ajax).

Heres the sorting code i have

```
$("#tableid tbody tr")
    .detach()
    .sort(function(a, b) {

        var dataA1 = $(a)
        .find("td:eq(5)")
        .text()
        .trim();

        var dataB1 = $(b)
        .find("td:eq(5)")
        .text()
        .trim();

        return parseFloat(dataA1.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB1.substring(

            1));

        })
        .appendTo('#tableid');
```

However i do have an issue with this that keeps happening

[image: table rows broken]

As you can see this is broken. the blank rows do have some text in and is in a `colspan 6`. What i'm wanting is these to be at the bottom of the table and the results at the top.

Any ideas how to do this?

**Edit**

```
<tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <td>
          <%= image_tag("provider-logo.png", style: "width: 140px") %>
        </td>
        <td colspan="6">
          No Tickets Are available from provider
        </td>
      </tr>
```

This is one of the table rows that has a colspan (i had put the colspan 6 in the filter)

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with what you already have, add a filter, and use `prependTo` instead of appendTo:

```
$("#tableid tbody tr")
    .filter(function() { return $(this).find('td[colspan="6"]').length == 0; })
    .detach()
    .sort(function(a, b) {

        var dataA1 = $(a)
        .find("td:eq(5)")
        .text()
        .trim();

        var dataB1 = $(b)
        .find("td:eq(5)")
        .text()
        .trim();

        return parseFloat(dataA1.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB1.substring(

            1));

        })
        .prependTo('#tableid');
```

Comment: Hey there,This didn't do anything different :). Thanks Sam

Comment: Wait missed the fikter, will try this shortly later and see what I get returned

Comment: Note: the filter I show is taking a guess at your markup based on your original question.  You may need to change the expression in the `find()` to something like: `find('td[colspan="6"]')`

Comment: Okay this made a slight difference. The layout is now blank price blank blank then the rest of the prices. (closer :D)

Comment: Please share the full HTML for one of your tables

Comment: I'll share the full html from an inspect element :)

Comment: Updated, Sorry about the delay :)

Comment: Answer updated.  If that doesn't work please supply HTML for full table